# Is there a planned StyleCop release for VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, stylecop

Does anyone know when stylecop will be released to integrate into VS2010. I know you can tweak the config files to integrate it at the moment, but it is not possible to view the UI.

Answer (score 1):

A beta was released on January 04, 2010.  It is easy to find via Google

Answer (score 1):

You can find it here: http://stylecop.codeplex.com/ still beta but works